# posting form in color box to parent form

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

So I am using the ColorBox code:
http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

What I want to do is to open a Color Box with a form.
User clicks on a button in Parent and opens ColorBox. 
User chooses from a select box inside the ColorBox.
Clicks submit and the option they selected gets added to a hidden field in the Parent form (the Parent that opened the ColorBox).

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Into which *concrete* problem did you run doing so?

Comment: I can open the color box, but I don't know how to post back to the parent. :(

Comment: You don't do that with a POST form, but instead with javascript and DOM manipulation, e.g. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3594621/Javascript-Basics-Part-6.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add value for your input hidden on the parent form using the keyword parent.

```
parent. $('# field').val(value);
```

And then close the fancybox:

```
$.colorbox.close();
```

or

```
parent.$.colorbox.close();
```